# Simple search in jQuery not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, search

I've jQuery script that I'm using to search through html tables and hide rows that are not matching entered string.

But it have some problem:
I have some elements with string 'Kable i przewody' and my search is working properly when I use strings with one letter or starting with any word in string ie.: 'Ka', 'prze' etc.

But It's not working with some strings using middle letters from words:
'able', 'rze', 'ody'.

This here is my code, please help:

```
    var query = getUrlParameter('q');


var $rows = $('.tabelapatrnerzy tr');
$('#szukaj').click(function() {

    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($('#wpisywane').val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ', /ą/i, '', /ź/i, 'z', /ż/i, 'z',/ó/i ,'o', /ł/i, 'l', /ń/i, 'n', /ć/i, 'c', /ę/i, 'e', /ś/i, 's');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});
if (query) {
    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim(query).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ', /ą/i, '', /ź/i, 'z', /ż/i, 'z',/ó/i ,'o', /ł/i, 'l', /ń/i, 'n', /ć/i, 'c', /ę/i, 'e', /ś/i, 's');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
}
```

Comment: If you need in-word matches, remove word boundaries, `\\b`s.

Comment: That was it, thanks. I must learn more about regex in js it seems. Please make answear so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\b` pattern matches a location at a word boundary.

To allow in-word matches, just remove all `\\b` in your patterns.

Comment: Would you also know how to make seach with spaces in input string possible?

Comment: Do not split the string with `/\s+/` regex then.